# Comparar "id" de dos objetos relacionados

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, condiciones

quizás resulte simple la pregunta para ustedes.

Utilizo los modelos **Bidon** y **Compra**, los cuales están relacionados, cuando muestro el detalle del bidón supongamos con ID: 1, en el estoy mostrando las últimas compras que se realizaron con ese bidón, lo que no logro conseguir es que cuando selecciono un bidón diferente, este me muestre las compras realizadas con ese bidón y no las últimas solamente.

este es el  (views/bidons/show.html.erb)

```
<% @compras.each do |compra| %>
<ul>
<li>
<small>Cantidad utilizada:</small> <span class="badge badge-inverse">
<small><%= compra.cantidad_comprada %></small></span> | <small>Producto:</small> 
<span class="badge badge-purple"><small><%= compra.product %></small></span>
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye">
</i>
<span class="sr-only">Detalles</span>'.html_safe, compra_path(compra), :title => "Mostrar detalles", :class => "green bigger-140 show-details-btn" %>
</li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

¿Cómo logro mostrar solo las compras realizadas con un bidón especifico?

Intente comprar los id correspondientes: @bidon.id y @compra.bidon_id, si estos dos son iguales, el resultado sería true en el show.html.erb, pero creo que me falta algo.

Agradezco su tiempo y comprensión.

Mosiah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, tu problema está en que @compras tiene todas las compras, y no solo las compras de tu bidón.
Suponiendo:

- Que tu vista tiene @bidon asignada al bidón relevante
- Compra belongs_to bidon
- Bidon has_many compras

Deberías poder hacer:

```
<% @bidon.compras.each do |compra| %>
```

Otra posibilidad, sería cambiar @compras en tu controlador por:

```
@compras = @bidon.compras
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hcarreras, es justo lo que necesitaba!